# Present Simple or Past Simple

Tags: tenses

Which is more common for native speakers to use in the following construction, present or past?

She is really a good friend and she never 'fails/failed' to send me a letter each month.

Comment: Is the friend continuing to send you letters each month (present simple), or did she send letters each month for some time in the past but no longer does (past simple)?

Comment: @geekahendron: So both are correct in case the action is still going on or stopped at some point of time in the past.

Comment: Neither is ambiguous. Saying "she never failed to send me a letter" indicates clearly that the action has stopped, and I would expect to see that phrasing coupled with some definitive time frame ("While I was away at college, she never failed to send me a letter each month."). In contrast, "she never fails to send me a letter" indicates clearly that the action is ongoing, and she is still sending you those letters.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also say *she **has never failed** to send me a letter.* (A phrasing that I personally prefer if I'm emphasizing a lack of some fault—assuming I don't say *she always sends me a letter*, the positive expression sounding more natural to me as a simple statement.)

Comment: @Jason: You're right, but with 'each day' it won't work.

Comment: @MidoMido That's true—but you wouldn't need to use it either. (However, *every day* would be fine.)

Comment: If you're emphasizing "good", which I think you are, I'd say "She is a really good friend".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common combination would be

> She is really a good friend and never fails to send me a letter each month.

Reason: it's nice when the two clauses linked by "and" are in the same tense, when the context permits that.  It certain does permit it here.